# Есть ли разница в употреблении: свои - твои со вторым лицом ед. ч.?

Tags: выбор-слов

Как правильно сказать и является ли ошибкой?

*Наконец-то ты разместил твои фотографии* или *Наконец-то ты разместил свои фотографии*?
Ты больше не скрываешь твое/свое милое лицо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Наконец-то ты разместил свои фотографии.
2. Ты больше не скрываешь  свое милое лицо. В этих предложениях правильно использовать слова "свои", "свое".
3. Где твои фотографии?
4. Твое лицо мне не нравится. В этих предложениях слова "свои", "свое" неуместны.

Answer (score 2):

Со вторым лицом так же, как и с первым. Сравните: Наконец-то  я разместил свои фотографии и Наконец-то я разместил твои фотографии. Понятно, кто что разместил.