# СВОИ или ТВОИ видеоролики?

Tags: местоимения

Как правильнее сказать: "не позорь СВОИ видеоролики" или "не позорь ТВОИ видеоролики"?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Есть ли разница в употреблении: свои - твои со вторым лицом ед.ч.?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30132/%d0%95%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b5%d0%b4-%d1%87)

Comment: Я против закрытия этого вопроса, да и вообще любых вопросов на эту тему. Все они очень конкретны и требуют ИНДИВИДУАЛЬНОГО подхода. В так называемых дубликатах очень часто дается ИНТУИТИВНЫЕ ответы, а теоретическое обоснование, как правило, отсутствует. И что тогда делать, сравнивать одну ситуацию с другой?  Не лучше ли применить правило Розенталя о возвратных местоимениях «свой, себя». Они потому и ВОЗВРАТНЫЕ, что тесно связаны с ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЕМ действия,  а эта мысль излагается  в ответах очень туманно. В частности, в ответах по ссылке я никакой теории не вижу.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Проблема** подобных вопросов заключается в следующем:

(1) Возвратно-притяжательное местоимение ***свой*** можно отнести **к любому из трех лиц**, в то время как обычные притяжательные местоимения *мой, твой, ваш, его, их* относятся к конкретному лицу (я, ты, вы, они).

(2) Выбор местоимений свой/твой связан **с действующим лицом.**

2. **Решение задачи**

Если местоимение относится к производителю действия, то выбор делается в пользу формы *свой*: *Не позорь **свои** видеоролики.* Предмет **принадлежит** производителю действия.

Но если сменить производителя, то возможна такая фраза: *Пусть он не позорит **твои** видеоролики.* Предмет **не принадлежит** производителю действия.

§170. Возвратные и притяжательные местоимения  http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm